# Substituting only unmasked values in a masked numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to substitute (only) unmasked values of an array (x) by ones **without changing masked values**. I have tried this,

```
 x = masked_array(data =
 [[1 -- 6 3]
 [3 -- 2 --]],
 mask =
 [[False  True False False]
 [False  True False  True]],
   fill_value = 999999)

 x[0,:] = 1.
```

but the result I got is not what I expected, since all values in the axis 0 were changed by 1, as I show here,

```
x = masked_array(data =
[[1 1 1 1]
[3 -- 2 --]],
mask =
[[False False False False]
[False  True False  True]],
   fill_value = 999999)
```

The result I expect to get looks like this:

```
 x = masked_array(data =
 [[1 -- 1 1]
 [3 -- 2 --]],        
 mask =
 [[False False False False]
 [False  True False  True]],
   fill_value = 999999)
```

Any insight on this?
Please note that this is just an example of my actual function, which uses very large masked netCDF files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slice into the `mask` of `x` and choose specific elements from the given line in `x`:

```
x[0,~x.mask[0,:]]=1
```

Before:

```
In [40]: x
Out[40]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 -- 6 3]
 [3 -- 2 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False False]
 [False  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

After:

```
In [42]: x
Out[42]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 -- 1 1]
 [3 -- 2 --]],
             mask =
 [[False  True False False]
 [False  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```